# What happened to the Vanishing Cabinets?

Tags: harry-potter

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16484/why-was-dumbledores-portrait-not-given-a-more-extant-role-in-the-story/16486#16486) mentions that a plausible in-universe reason for not talking to Dumbledore's portrait in Deathly Hallows was that the school was under Snape/DeathEater control. Also, they had to use Aberforth's tunnel to get to the school in the end.

They could have considered using the same method that Malfoy used to bring DE's to the school at the end of HBP - The Vanishing Cabinets.

**So, is there any canon explanation of what happened to both Vanishing Cabinets (one in the Room of Requirement, one in... wherever) after HBP?**

<sub>I'm not asking whether this would be a good idea (probably bad - DEs knew about the cabinets and would have guarded them, hopefully).</sub>

Comment: Just to be clear - the whole reason I mentioned the Trio not using the cabinets was to clarify the timeframe I'm interested in - **BETWEEN the end of HBP, and the time the Trio got into the school right before the battle of Hogwarts**. I'm not at all interested in why they didn't use the cabinets, just whether we know what the status/location of cabinets was.

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know nothing happened to the cabinets, however it would have been impossible to use them with all the student refugees occupying the RoR.

As the Vanishing Cabinet only exists in the Room of Hidden Things or whatever the carboot sale room is called it would technically at that point in time not exist or as Minerva would put it.

> “Where do vanished objects go?"
>   "Into nonbeing, which is to say, everything," replied Professor McGonagall.

Answer (score 0):

The vanishing cabinet in the Room of Requirement was very likely destroyed by the fiendfyre curse.  Book 7, Ch. 31 has Ron asking "...d'you reckon it'll (RoR) still work after that fire?", and Hermione later says "Fiendfyre- cursed fire- it's one of the substances that destroy horcruxes...".  It destroyed the diadem of Ravenclaw. There is little doubt that all items hidden in the RoR were consumed.

As far as the cabinet at Borgin and Burkes... it was likely confiscated, or trashed once it's sister was destroyed.

I have not read canon other than the 7 books, so there might be other intel available.

Comment: No. The Fiendfyre was *after* the OP's intended timeline.